# Win32 How to select and make active item in combobox?

Tags: winapi, select, combobox

I'm trying to select item from combobox list and make it active (or apply it) to press a button control next...
What's a proper way to do it? Should I use GetComboBoxInfo() to get a list of items? How do I select after that? Also, maybe easier way to select it with a mouse?
So, in short I need 1) to get a list of items; 2) select item I need (either by respective string value or my some index as per some dictionary).

Comment: `ComboBox_SetCurSel` or direct `CB_SETCURSEL`

Comment: You can send a [`CB_SELECTSTRING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/cb-selectstring) or [`CB_SETCURSEL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/cb-setcursel) message to the control. Although I'm having a feeling, that this is about selecting an item in a different application. In that case, use [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32).

Comment: How do I use UI Automation? Any manual or functions description? Any sample of usage UI Automation in respect to Combobox item selection?

Comment: First, read the docs then ask questions about what you don't understand. Microsoft has put out an enormous amount of material about the windows API over the years.